# REST API allow update of resource depending on state of resource

Tags: rest, put, restful-url

I have recently read the guide on implementing RESTful API's in Spring Boot from the official Spring.io tutorials website (link to tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)

However, something in the guide seemed to contradict my understanding of how REST API's should be built. I am now wondering if my understanding is wrong or if the guide is not of as high a quality as I expected it to be.

My problem is with this implementation of a PUT method to update the status of an order:

```
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable Long id) {

  Order order = orderRepository.findById(id) //
      .orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(id));

  if (order.getStatus() == Status.IN_PROGRESS) {
    order.setStatus(Status.COMPLETED);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toModel(orderRepository.save(order)));
  }

  return ResponseEntity //
      .status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) //
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaTypes.HTTP_PROBLEM_DETAILS_JSON_VALUE) //
      .body(Problem.create() //
          .withTitle("Method not allowed") //
          .withDetail("You can't complete an order that is in the " + order.getStatus() + " status"));
}
```

From what I read at https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/ a PUT method should be idempotent; meaning that you should be able to call it multiple times in a row without it causing problems. However, in this implementation only the first PUT request would have an effect and all further PUT requests to the same resource would result in an error message.

Is this okay according to RESTful API's? If not, what would be a better method to use? I don't think POST would be any better.

Also, in the same guide, they use the DELETE method in a similar way to change the status of an order to cancelled:

```
@DeleteMapping("/orders/{id}/cancel")
ResponseEntity<?> cancel(@PathVariable Long id) {

  Order order = orderRepository.findById(id) //
      .orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(id));

  if (order.getStatus() == Status.IN_PROGRESS) {
    order.setStatus(Status.CANCELLED);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toModel(orderRepository.save(order)));
  }

  return ResponseEntity //
      .status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED) //
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaTypes.HTTP_PROBLEM_DETAILS_JSON_VALUE) //
      .body(Problem.create() //
          .withTitle("Method not allowed") //
          .withDetail("You can't cancel an order that is in the " + order.getStatus() + " status"));
}
```

This looks very wrong to me. We are not deleting anything here, it is basically the same as the previous PUT method just with a different state we want to move to. Am I correct to assume that this part of the tutorial is bogus?

**TL;DR:** what HTTP method is right to use when you want to advance the status of a resource to the next stage without giving an option of going back to an earlier stage? Basically an update/patch that will invalidate its own pre-conditions.

Comment: technically it is idempotent. No matter how many times you PUT to /complete it will only complete once, when the order status is Status.IN_PROGRESS. All other calls will result in HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED as you're trying to complete a completed order. Same for DELETE. You can only delete it once. idempotency is on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something in the guide seemed to contradict my understanding of how REST API's should be built. I am now wondering if my understanding is wrong or if the guide is not of as high a quality as I expected it to be.

I wouldn't consider this guide to be a reliable authority - the described resource model has some very questionable choices.

---

> From what I read at https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/ a PUT method should be idempotent; meaning that you should be able to call it multiple times in a row without it causing problems. However, in this implementation only the first PUT request would have an effect and all further PUT requests to the same resource would result in an error message.

The authoritative definition of idempotent semantics in HTTP is currently [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.2).

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.

Note: "effect", not "response".

```
PUT /orders/12345/complete
```

means "please replace the current representation of /orders/12345/complete with the representation in the payload".  In other words "save this file on top of your current copy".  Saving the same file two or three times in row produces the same effect as saving the file once, so that's "idempotent".

> HTTP does not define exactly how a PUT method affects the state of an origin server beyond what can be expressed by the intent of the user agent request and the semantics of the origin server response.  It does not define what a resource might be, in any sense of that word, beyond the interface provided via HTTP.  It does not define how   resource state is "stored", nor how such storage might change as a result of a change in resource state, nor how the origin server translates resource state into representations.  Generally speaking, all implementation details behind the resource interface are intentionally hidden by the server. -- [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

So in their CURL example

```
PUT /orders/4/complete HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
```

The meaning of this message is "replace the current representation of /orders/4/complete with an empty representation".  But the origin server gets to choose how to do that, and which standardized responses to return to the client.

So this is *fine*.

> All work is transacted by politely placing documents in in-trays, and then some side effect of placing that document in an in-tray causes some business activity to occur -- [Jim Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s).

In this case, the document we are putting into the "in-tray" happens to be blank.

---

```
@DeleteMapping("/orders/{id}/cancel")
```

I would never approve that choice in a code review.  [DELETE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) (like PUT) has semantics in the "transfer of documents over a network domain".

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server remove the association between the target resource and its current functionality.  In effect, this method is similar to the rm command in UNIX: it expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping of the  origin server rather than an expectation that the previously associated information be deleted.

Trying to hijack the method because the spelling is kind of like the domain action is the wrong heuristic to use in choosing methods.

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect.

The point being that we have a general purpose document manipulation interface, and we are using that interface as a *facade* that allows us to drive business activity.  So we should be using our standardized message semantics *the same way every other page on the web does*.

@PutMapping would be defensible, using the same justification as we did for /complete.

---

> what HTTP method is right to use when you want to advance the status of a resource to the next stage without giving an option of going back to an earlier stage? Basically an update/patch that will invalidate its own pre-conditions.

PUT, PATCH, and POST are all appropriate methods to use when editing the representation of a resource.  Use PUT or PATCH when you are sending a replacement representation for the resource, use POST when you are asking the server to calculate what the edit to the representation should be.